# Missing gmail plugins

Tags: gmail-addons

So I received 2 emails with the same content but different senders. In the first email, the plugins are missing. While in the second one, all my plugins are visible. I tried checking the original content and in the first email, the `SPF` status is `SOFTFAIL`, while on the second one, `SPF`, `DKIM` and `DMARC` are all `PASS`.

First email original content:

[image: First email original content]

Second email original content:

[image: Second email original content]

Is this somehow connected why my gmail plugins went missing? Does google prevent using gmail plugins if there is a `SOFTFAIL` or `FAIL` status in `SPF`, `DKIM` or `DMARC`? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the bug logged here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76458977. Hope this helps